# How to reconfigure grub on a backed up arch linux on a USB flash disk

Tags: rsync, backup, grub, fstab

i managed to back up my arch linux suing rsync :

```
# rsync -aAXv --exclude={"/dev/*","/proc/*","/sys/*","/tmp/*","/run/*","/mnt/*","/media/*","/lost+found"} / /run/media/username/archlinux
```

edited fstab :

```
#
# /etc/fstab: static file system information
#
# <file system> <dir>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# /dev/sda3
UUID=d2b779b2-b2b1-48d6-8493-6468f99a0a21       /               ext4            rw,relatime,data=ordered        0 1

# /dev/sda6
UUID=be9152a7-3178-44ba-b3d8-0448e9dd4c80       /boot           ext4            rw,relatime,data=ordered        0 2

# /dev/sda5
UUID=5b2ce0ad-9d59-4023-8ca6-f6a6bbdd59e7       none            swap            defaults        0 0
```

> > > >

```
#
# /etc/fstab: static file system information
#
# <file system> <dir>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# /dev/sda3
UUID=The UUID of the USB drive       /               ext4            rw,relatime,data=ordered        0 1
```

and then regenerated the grub config via grub-mkconfig:

```
sudo grub-mkconfig -o /run/media/username/archlinux/boot/grub/grub.cfg
```

and it returns:

```
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-linux
Found initrd image: /boot/initramfs-linux.img
Found fallback initramfs image: /boot/initramfs-linux-fallback.img
Found Windows 10 (loader) on /dev/sda1
Found Arch on /dev/sdb1
done
```

but the UUID of /boot/grub/grub.cfg is the UUID of my original partition not my bakcup even though seems like grub is finding  an arch installation on my usb stick  (Found Arch on /dev/sdb1)

int the arch linux wiki it is recommended to use mkinitcpio:

```
# mkdir /mnt/arch
# mount /dev/sdb3 /mnt/arch
# cd /mnt/arch
# mount -t proc proc proc/
# mount --rbind /sys sys/
# mount --rbind /dev dev/
# chroot /mnt/arch /bin/bash
# mkinitcpio -p linux
```

but the UUID is still the same. i have ran this operation many times but i get the same result.it doesn't even load the grub when i boot with my usb, it goes straight to my original grub  not the one installed on the USB. on a different USB it leads to a back screen and i have to remove the USB to see the grub installed on my hard drive. 
any help would be appreciated

Comment: Post your full grub.cfg file to a pastebin website and link it in your question